# How to close searchView in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) when onBackPressed don't work?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-search

Need code to close the searchView when BACK is pressed. So far only have code that closes the keyboard when BACK is pressed.

[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


   if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
       if (view != null) {
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

I tried the following line but this line closes the entire app for some reason when "back" clicked on...

```
 onBackPressed();
```

The following line is deprecated...

```
   MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menuItem);
```

I've seen some answers on stackOverflow but most of them have to do with `onBackPressed()` or adding `searchView.collapseActionView()`.
But I can't add searchView in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` unless I redeclare it with `SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();` and then add `searchView.collapseActionView()` but then the app crashes when BACK pressed.

I got the keyboard to close but how do I close the searchView in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` ?

**EDIT:**

When I use `onBackPressed()` or `super.onBackPressed()` or `this.onBackPressed()`, the first time I click on "back" button, searchView and keyboard close, but when I click on search Icon again to open searchView and keyboard pops up, if I click on "back" again, the entire app closes, not crashes, just closes and takes me to Android Phone home screen. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!yourSearhView.isIconified()) {
            yourSearhView.onActionViewCollapsed();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

This won't work if the you have set app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: This code don't work for me, I've seen it on stackOverflow.

Comment: You know of code I can place inside onOptionsItemSelected that won't require me to use "searchView". Like the keyboard hide code, where I didn't have to input "searchView".